# Cross-compile toolchain can't find crt1.o files

Tags: c++, g++, cross-platform, pi

I am trying to cross-compile on my Linux x86_64 computer with target Raspberry pi 64-bit.  I am following [this nice guide](https://mechatronicsblog.com/cross-compile-and-deploy-qt-5-12-for-raspberry-pi/).  So far things have been working well.  But when I run configure it fails with "The toolchain or QMakeSpec is broken.":

```
[root@fedora qt-everywhere-src-5.15.2]# ./configure -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi3-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot ~/raspi/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -skip qtwayland -skip qtlocation -skip qtscript -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix ~/raspi/qt5pi -hostprefix ~/raspi/qt5 -no-use-gold-linker -v -no-gbm
+ cd qtbase
+ /root/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.2/qtbase/configure -top-level -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi3-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/root/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot /root/raspi/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -skip qtwayland -skip qtlocation -skip qtscript -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix /root/raspi/qt5pi -hostprefix /root/raspi/qt5 -no-use-gold-linker -v -no-gbm
Creating qmake...
gmake: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
Command line: -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi3-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/root/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot /root/raspi/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -skip qtwayland -skip qtlocation -skip qtscript -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix /root/raspi/qt5pi -hostprefix /root/raspi/qt5 -no-use-gold-linker -v -no-gbm

This is the Qt Open Source Edition.

You have already accepted the terms of the Open Source license.

Running configuration tests...

+ /root/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -dumpmachine
> arm-linux-gnueabihf
Checking for valid makespec... 
+ cd /root/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.2/config.tests/verifyspec && /root/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.2/qtbase/bin/qmake "CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle" "CONFIG += shared warn_off console single_arch" "QMAKE_CFLAGS += --sysroot=/root/raspi/sysroot" "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += --sysroot=/root/raspi/sysroot" "QMAKE_LFLAGS += --sysroot=/root/raspi/sysroot" -early "CONFIG += cross_compile" /root/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.2/qtbase/config.tests/verifyspec
+ cd /root/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.2/config.tests/verifyspec && MAKEFLAGS= /bin/gmake clean && MAKEFLAGS= /bin/gmake
> rm -f verifyspec.o
> rm -f *~ core *.core
> /root/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -c -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a53 -mfpu=crypto-neon-fp-armv8 -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=/root/raspi/sysroot -O2 -std=gnu++11 -w -fPIC  -I/root/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.2/qtbase/config.tests/verifyspec -I. -I/root/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.2/qtbase/mkspecs/devices/linux-rasp-pi3-g++ -o verifyspec.o /root/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.2/qtbase/config.tests/verifyspec/verifyspec.cpp
> /root/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=/root/raspi/sysroot -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath-link,/root/raspi/sysroot/opt/vc/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/root/raspi/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -Wl,-rpath-link,/root/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -o verifyspec verifyspec.o      
> /root/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
> /root/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
> /root/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> gmake: *** [Makefile:68: verifyspec] Error 1
Note: Also available for Linux: linux-clang linux-icc

ERROR: Cannot compile a minimal program. The toolchain or QMakeSpec is broken.
```

So I checked if the crt1.o file exists under the current directory and it does"

```
[root@fedora qt-everywhere-src-5.15.2]# find / -name crt1.o
/root/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/crt1.o
/root/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/crt1.o
/root/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/lib/crt1.o
/root/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o
/root/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o
/root/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o
/root/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o
/root/raspi/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
```

So the g++ compiler isn't looking the the right dir.  I confirmed with g++ -print-search-dirs that it's not looking in the right dir above.  But...how do I append the right directory to the G++ search path?  I tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH and also adding path to ldconfig command, but still not found.  Must be something else

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

According to various posts online, the git raspberry toolchain is severly out of date.  So I downloaded the latest toolchain from ARM directly [here](https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/arm-gnu-toolchain-downloads) and then the problem was resolve.

There are still a couple of Qt makespec files that need to be tweeked, but using the arm toolchain solved a variety of issues.